# How do I implement my own semaphore in C?

Tags: c, function, semaphore, consumer, producer

I'm working on solving the Producer/Consumer problem through different methods. The one I'm currently working on involves my own implementation of a semaphore, paired with Peterson's solution to protect the semaphore's down() and up() function calls.

The problem is, I'm working in C, and the only way I can think of creating a semaphore would be to use a struct with function pointers for down() and up(). Is this the right idea?

Comment: The function pointers seem unrelated to the problem: you can call `up(my_semaphore);` instead of `my_semaphore->up(my_semaphore);`. (In C you can't really have `my_semaphore->up()` without arguments, since there is no implicit `this` argument passed so that the function would know which semaphore called it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will likely want to use some OS-provided or hardware-provided synchronization primitive. Examples include system calls (e.g. Linux's `futex` call, Windows' `EnterCriticalSection`), hardware swap calls (e.g. `cmpxchg` on x86, `ldrex/strex` on ARM), or library functions which use one of these methods (e.g. `pthread_mutex`).

Trying to do synchronization without any help from the OS or hardware is likely to be quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Check  [futex](http://www.helenos.org/doc/design/html.chunked/sync.html), it is a user space syn primitive. But I don't think you're looking for something this much complicated.